Implementing the Huffman's data compression algorithm in AEC and compiling it to WebAssembly
A few years ago, I implemented the Huffman's data compression algorithm in JavaScript. Now I've implemented it in my programming language, AEC. You can see it live (at least in very modern browsers) here. Here is the code:
Function noMoreFreeMemory() Which Returns Nothing Is External;
Function segmentationFault() Which Returns Nothing Is External;
Function
printString(PointerToCharacter string) Which Returns Nothing Is External;
Function clearScreen() Which Returns Nothing Is External;
Function getLengthOfTheInput() Which Returns Integer16 Is External;
Function
getCharacterOfTheInput(Integer16 index) Which Returns Character Is External;

Integer32 NDEBUG : = 1;

Structure TreeNode Consists Of {
  Character character;
  Integer16 frequencyOfCharacter;
  PointerToTreeNode leftChild, rightChild;
  Character code[16];
}
EndStructure;

InstantiateStructure TreeNode treeNodes[64];
Integer16 isTreeNodeUsed[64];

Function isTreeNodeWithinBounds(
    PointerToTreeNode treeNode) Which Returns Integer32 Does {
  Return AddressOf(treeNodes[0]) <= treeNode <= AddressOf(treeNodes[64 - 1]) and
      mod(treeNode - AddressOf(treeNodes[0]), SizeOf(TreeNode)) = 0;
}
EndFunction;

Function
convertIntegerToString(PointerToCharacter string,
                       Integer32 integer) Which Returns Nothing Is Declared;
Function strcat(PointerToCharacter dest,
                PointerToCharacter src) Which Returns Nothing Is Declared;
Function strlen(PointerToCharacter string) Which Returns Integer32 Is Declared;

Function newTreeNode() Which Returns PointerToTreeNode Does {
  Integer16 i : = 0;
  While i < 64 Loop {
    If not(isTreeNodeUsed[i]) Then {
      treeNodes[i].character : = 0;
      treeNodes[i].leftChild : = treeNodes[i].rightChild
          : = PointerToTreeNode(0);
      treeNodes[i].code[0] : = 0;
      treeNodes[i].frequencyOfCharacter : = 0;
      isTreeNodeUsed[i] : = 1;
      If NDEBUG = 0 Then {
        Character stringToBePrinted[64] : = {0};
        strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]),
               "NDEBUG: Allocating the TreeNode #");
        convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                                   strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                               i);
        strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), "\n");
        printString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]));
      }
      EndIf;
      Return AddressOf(treeNodes[i]);
    }
    EndIf;
    i += 1;
  }
  EndWhile;
  noMoreFreeMemory();
}
EndFunction;

Function freeTreeNode(PointerToTreeNode treeNode) Which Returns Nothing Does {
  If not(isTreeNodeWithinBounds(treeNode)) Then { segmentationFault(); }
  EndIf;
  If NDEBUG = 0 Then {
    Character stringToBePrinted[64] : = {0};
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), "NDEBUG: Freeing the TreeNode #");
    convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                               strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                           (treeNode - AddressOf(treeNodes[0])) /
                               SizeOf(TreeNode));
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), "\n");
    printString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]));
  }
  EndIf;
  isTreeNodeUsed[(treeNode - AddressOf(treeNodes[0])) / SizeOf(TreeNode)] : = 0;
}
EndFunction;

Function strlen(PointerToCharacter str) Which Returns Integer32 Does {
  Integer32 length : = 0;
  While ValueAt(str + length) Loop { length += 1; }
  EndWhile;
  Return length;
}
EndFunction;

Function strcpy(PointerToCharacter dest,
                PointerToCharacter src) Which Returns Nothing Does {
  While ValueAt(src) Loop {
    ValueAt(dest) : = ValueAt(src);
    dest += 1;
    src += 1;
  }
  EndWhile;
  ValueAt(dest) : = 0;
}
EndFunction;

Function strcat(PointerToCharacter dest,
                PointerToCharacter src) Which Returns Nothing Does {
  strcpy(dest + strlen(dest), src);
}
EndFunction;

Function reverseString(PointerToCharacter string) Which Returns Nothing Does {
  PointerToCharacter pointerToLastCharacter : = string + strlen(string) - 1;
  While pointerToLastCharacter - string > 0 Loop {
    Character tmp : = ValueAt(string);
    ValueAt(string) : = ValueAt(pointerToLastCharacter);
    ValueAt(pointerToLastCharacter) : = tmp;
    string += 1;
    pointerToLastCharacter -= 1;
  }
  EndWhile;
}
EndFunction;

Function convertIntegerToString(PointerToCharacter string,
                                Integer32 number) Which Returns Nothing Does {
  Integer32 isNumberNegative : = 0;
  If number < 0 Then {
  number:
    = -number;
  isNumberNegative:
    = 1;
  }
  EndIf;
  Integer32 i : = 0;
  While number >= 10 Loop {
    ValueAt(string + i) : = '0' + mod(number, 10);
    number /= 10;
    i += 1;
  }
  EndWhile;
  ValueAt(string + i) : = '0' + number;
  i += 1;
  If isNumberNegative Then {
    ValueAt(string + i) : = '-';
    i += 1;
  }
  EndIf;
  ValueAt(string + i) : = 0;
  reverseString(string);
}
EndFunction;

Function convertDecimalToString(PointerToCharacter string,
                                Decimal32 number) Which Returns Nothing Does {
  convertIntegerToString(string, number);
  number -= Integer32(number);
  If number < 0 Then { number *= -1; }
  EndIf;
  If number = 0 Then { Return; }
  EndIf;
  strcat(string, ".");
  Integer16 numberOfDecimals : = 0;
  While numberOfDecimals<3 and number> 0 Loop {
    numberOfDecimals += 1;
    number *= 10;
    Character stringWithTheNewDigit[2];
    stringWithTheNewDigit[0] : = stringWithTheNewDigit[1] : = 0;
    stringWithTheNewDigit[0] : = '0' + number;
    strcat(string, AddressOf(stringWithTheNewDigit[0]));
    number -= Integer32(number);
  }
  EndWhile;
}
EndFunction;

PointerToCharacter mapOfCodes[256];

Function assignCode(PointerToCharacter currentCode,
                    PointerToTreeNode treeNode) Which Returns Nothing Does {
  If NDEBUG = 0 Then {
    Character stringToBePrinted[64] : = {0};
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), "NDEBUG: Assigning the code \"");
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), currentCode);
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), "\" to the TreeNode #");
    convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                               strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                           (treeNode - AddressOf(treeNodes[0])) /
                               SizeOf(TreeNode));
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), ".\n");
    printString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]));

    stringToBePrinted[0] : = 0;
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]),
           "NDEBUG: Its left child is the TreeNode #");
    If treeNode->leftChild Then {
      convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                                 strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                             (treeNode->leftChild - AddressOf(treeNodes[0])) /
                                 SizeOf(TreeNode));
    }
    Else { strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), "null"); }
    EndIf;
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), ".\n");
    printString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]));

    stringToBePrinted[0] : = 0;
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]),
           "NDEBUG: Its right child is the TreeNode #");
    If treeNode->leftChild Then {
      convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                                 strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                             (treeNode->rightChild - AddressOf(treeNodes[0])) /
                                 SizeOf(TreeNode));
    }
    Else { strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), "null"); }
    EndIf;
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), ".\n");
    printString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]));
  }
  EndIf;

  If not(isTreeNodeWithinBounds(treeNode)) Then { segmentationFault(); }
  EndIf;

  strcpy(AddressOf(treeNode->code[0]), currentCode);

  Character leftCode[16] : = {0}, rightCode[16] : = {0};

  strcpy(AddressOf(leftCode[0]), currentCode);
  strcat(AddressOf(leftCode[0]), "0");
  strcpy(AddressOf(rightCode[0]), currentCode);
  strcat(AddressOf(rightCode[0]), "1");

  If treeNode->leftChild Then {
    assignCode(AddressOf(leftCode[0]), treeNode->leftChild);
  }
  EndIf;
  If treeNode->rightChild Then {
    assignCode(AddressOf(rightCode[0]), treeNode->rightChild);
  }
  EndIf;

  If treeNode->character Then {
    mapOfCodes[treeNode->character] : = AddressOf(treeNode->code[0]);
    Character codeToPrint[32] : = {0};
    codeToPrint[0] : = '\'';
    codeToPrint[1] : = treeNode->character;
    codeToPrint[2] : = '\'';
    codeToPrint[3] : = '=';
    codeToPrint[4] : = '>';
    codeToPrint[5] : = 0;
    strcat(AddressOf(codeToPrint[0]), AddressOf(treeNode->code[0]));
    strcat(AddressOf(codeToPrint[0]), "\n");
    printString(AddressOf(codeToPrint[0]));
  }
  EndIf;
}
EndFunction;

Function freeUpTheTree(PointerToTreeNode tree) Which Returns Nothing Does {
  If tree->leftChild Then {
    freeUpTheTree(tree->leftChild); // Calling `freeTreeNode` here instead of
                                    // `freeUpTheTree` causes a memory leak.
  }
  EndIf;
  If tree->rightChild Then { freeUpTheTree(tree->rightChild); }
  EndIf;
  freeTreeNode(tree);
}
EndFunction;

Decimal32 PRECISION : = 500;
Function ln(Decimal32 x) Which Returns Decimal32 Does {
  // Natural logarithm is the integral of 1/x from 1 to x, highschool math.
  Decimal32 sum : = 0, epsilon : = (x - 1) / (5 * PRECISION), i : = 1;
  While(epsilon > 0 and i < x) or (epsilon < 0 and i > x) Loop {
    sum += epsilon / i;
    i += epsilon;
  }
  EndWhile;
  Return sum;
}
EndFunction;

Function log2(Decimal32 x) Which Returns Decimal32 Does {
  Return ln(x) / ln(2);
}
EndFunction;

Character input[32];
Character output[256];

Function main() Which Returns Nothing Does {
  clearScreen();
  Integer16 lengthOfInput : = getLengthOfTheInput(), i : = 0;
  If NDEBUG = 0 Then {
    Character stringToBePrinted[64] : = {0};
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]),
           "NDEBUG: The length of the input is: ");
    convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                               strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                           lengthOfInput);
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), "\n");
    printString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]));
  }
  EndIf;
  While i < lengthOfInput Loop {
    input[i] : = getCharacterOfTheInput(i);
    i += 1;
  }
  EndWhile;
  input[lengthOfInput] : = 0;

  If strlen(AddressOf(input[0])) = 0 Then {
    printString("The input is empty!\n");
    Return;
  }
  EndIf;
  PointerToTreeNode array[32];
  Integer16 lengthOfTheArray : = 0;
i:
  = 0;
  While i < lengthOfInput Loop {
    Integer16 j : = 0, haveWeFoundTheCharacterInTheArray : = 0;
    While j < lengthOfTheArray Loop {
      If array[j]->character = input[i] Then {
      haveWeFoundTheCharacterInTheArray:
        = 1;
        array[j]->frequencyOfCharacter += 1;
      }
      EndIf;
      j += 1;
    }
    EndWhile;
    If not(haveWeFoundTheCharacterInTheArray) Then {
      array[lengthOfTheArray] : = newTreeNode();
      array[lengthOfTheArray]->character : = input[i];
      array[lengthOfTheArray]->frequencyOfCharacter : = 1;
      lengthOfTheArray += 1;
    }
    EndIf;
    i += 1;
  }
  EndWhile;

i:
  = 0;
  While i < lengthOfTheArray Loop {
    Character stringToBePrinted[64] : = {0};
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), "The character '");
    Integer16 indexOfCharacter : = strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]));
    stringToBePrinted[indexOfCharacter] : = array[i]->character;
    stringToBePrinted[indexOfCharacter + 1] : = 0;
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), "' has the frequency of ");
    convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                               strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                           array[i]->frequencyOfCharacter);
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), ".\n");
    printString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]));
    i += 1;
  }
  EndWhile;

  Decimal32 ShannonEntropy : = 0;
i:
  = 0;
  While i < lengthOfTheArray Loop {
    ShannonEntropy -=
        (array[i]->frequencyOfCharacter / Decimal32(lengthOfInput)) *
        log2(array[i]->frequencyOfCharacter / Decimal32(lengthOfInput));
    i += 1;
  }
  EndWhile;
  output[0] : = 0;
  strcat(AddressOf(output[0]), "The Shannon Entropy of the input string is: ");
  convertDecimalToString(AddressOf(output[0]) + strlen(AddressOf(output[0])),
                         ShannonEntropy);
  strcat(AddressOf(output[0]), " bits/symbol.\n");
  printString(AddressOf(output[0]));

  While lengthOfTheArray > 1 Loop {
    Integer16 minimum : = 0, secondMinimum : = 0;

    Integer16 i : = 0;
    If NDEBUG = 0 Then {
      Character stringToBePrinted[64] : = {0};
      strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]),
             "NDEBUG: The length of the array is ");
      convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                                 strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                             lengthOfTheArray);
      strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), ".\n");
      printString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]));
    }
    EndIf;
    While i < lengthOfTheArray Loop {
      If NDEBUG = 0 Then {
        Character stringToBePrinted[64] : = {0};
        strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]),
               "NDEBUG: The tree at the index #");
        convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                                   strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                               i);
        strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), " is the TreeNode #");
        convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                                   strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                               (array[i] - AddressOf(treeNodes[0])) /
                                   SizeOf(TreeNode));
        strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), ".\n");
        printString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]));
      }
      EndIf;
      If not(isTreeNodeWithinBounds(array[i])) Then {
        segmentationFault();
        Return;
      }
      EndIf;
      i += 1;
    }
    EndWhile;

  i:
    = 0;
    While i < lengthOfTheArray Loop {
      If array[i]->frequencyOfCharacter <
          array[minimum]->frequencyOfCharacter Then {
      minimum:
        = i;
      }
      EndIf;
      i += 1;
    }
    EndWhile;

  i:
    = minimum = 0 ? 1 : 0;
  secondMinimum:
    = i;
    While i < lengthOfTheArray Loop {
      If array[i]->frequencyOfCharacter <
              array[secondMinimum]->frequencyOfCharacter and
          not(i = minimum) Then {
      secondMinimum:
        = i;
      }
      EndIf;
      i += 1;
    }
    EndWhile;

    If NDEBUG = 0 Then {
      Character stringToBePrinted[64] : = {0};
      strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]),
             "NDEBUG: The minimum and the second minimum are ");
      convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                                 strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                             minimum);
      strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), " and ");
      convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                                 strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                             secondMinimum);
      strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), ".\n");
      printString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]));
    }
    EndIf;

    If NDEBUG = 0 Then {
      Character stringToBePrinted[64] : = {0};
      strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), "NDEBUG: Joining the TreeNode #");
      convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                                 strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                             (array[minimum] - AddressOf(treeNodes[0])) /
                                 SizeOf(TreeNode));
      strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), " with the TreeNode #");
      convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                                 strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                             (array[secondMinimum] - AddressOf(treeNodes[0])) /
                                 SizeOf(TreeNode));
      strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), ".\n");
      printString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]));
    }
    EndIf;

    PointerToTreeNode sumOfTheTwoMostFrequent : = newTreeNode();
    sumOfTheTwoMostFrequent->frequencyOfCharacter
        : = array[minimum]->frequencyOfCharacter +
            array[secondMinimum]->frequencyOfCharacter;
    sumOfTheTwoMostFrequent->leftChild : = array[minimum];
    sumOfTheTwoMostFrequent->rightChild : = array[secondMinimum];

    If NDEBUG = 0 Then {
      Character stringToBePrinted[64] : = {0};
      strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]),
             "NDEBUG: The new TreeNode has the frequency of: ");
      convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                                 strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                             sumOfTheTwoMostFrequent->frequencyOfCharacter);
      strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), ".\n");
      printString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]));
    }
    EndIf;

    array[minimum] : = sumOfTheTwoMostFrequent;

  i:
    = secondMinimum;
    While i < lengthOfTheArray - 1 Loop {
      array[i] : = array[i + 1];
      i += 1;
    }
    EndWhile;

    lengthOfTheArray -= 1;
  }
  EndWhile;

  If NDEBUG = 0 Then {
    Character stringToBePrinted[128] : = {0};
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]),
           "NDEBUG: The frequency of the root node is ");
    convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                               strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                           array[0]->frequencyOfCharacter);
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]),
           ". If the algorithm is correctly implemented, it should be ");
    convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]) +
                               strlen(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0])),
                           lengthOfInput);
    strcat(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]), ".\n");
    printString(AddressOf(stringToBePrinted[0]));
  }
  EndIf;

  assignCode("", array[0]);

  Integer16 lengthOfTheOutput : = 0;
i:
  = 0;
  While i < lengthOfInput Loop {
    lengthOfTheOutput += strlen(mapOfCodes[input[i]]);
    i += 1;
  }
  EndWhile;
  output[0] : = 0;
  strcat(AddressOf(output[0]), "The length of the encoded string is: ");
  convertIntegerToString(AddressOf(output[0]) + strlen(AddressOf(output[0])),
                         lengthOfTheOutput);
  strcat(AddressOf(output[0]), " bits.\n");
  printString(AddressOf(output[0]));

  output[0] : = 0;
  strcat(AddressOf(output[0]),
         "The average length of the symbol in the Huffman code is: ");
  convertDecimalToString(AddressOf(output[0]) + strlen(AddressOf(output[0])),
                         Decimal32(lengthOfTheOutput) / lengthOfInput);
  strcat(AddressOf(output[0]), " bits/symbol.\n");
  printString(AddressOf(output[0]));

  output[0] : = 0;
i:
  = 0;
  While i < lengthOfInput Loop {
    strcat(AddressOf(output[0]), mapOfCodes[input[i]]);
    i += 1;
  }
  EndWhile;
  strcat(AddressOf(output[0]), "\n");
  printString(AddressOf(output[0]));

  freeUpTheTree(array[0]);
}
EndFunction;




